# Probability of an event given conditional and unconditional probabilities

Tags: conditional-probability

Let's assume the following:

a) the conditional probability of $B$ given $A$ is 0.8

b) the conditional probability of $B$ given $\text{not }A$ is 0.4

c) the unconditional probability of $B$ is 0.5

What is the probability of $A$?

**EDIT**

I'm really struggling with this.  Here is what I'm thinking and could really use some help.

$$P(B) - P(B|\text{not }A) \cdot P(\text{not }A) = P(B|A) \cdot P(A) \implies P(\text{not }A)=1-P(A)$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Without (much) math - see [weighted average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean).  Then, attack with intuition.  (0.4) is three times closer to (0.5) than is (0.8).

Comment: While I appreciate that you're attempt to be helpful, I don't understand this part:  " (0.4) is three times closer to (0.5) than is (0.8)".  The genesis of my question was really:  "Is there a closed-form solution to solve for a probability when you know the conditional and unconditional probabilities?"

Comment: You can use the definitions to write a set of mathematical equations, each equation corresponding to a given piece of information.

Comment: Is the formula the following?  P(A) = [P(B) * P(B | A)] + [P(B) * P(B | not A)] = 0.6

Comment: What you have done in the edits are correct! Just use $1-P(A)$ instead of $P(\text{not} A)$ as you said and solve for $P(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The law of total probability states $P(A)=\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^k P(B_j)P(A|B_j)$ with $B_1,...,B_k$ a partition of the sample space.

Here, $A$ and $A^c$ form a partition of the sample space, and also A and B are switched around from the statement of the law. We have $P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^c)P(A^c)$

$.5=.8P(A)+.4(1-P(A))$

$P(A)=.25$